# Navigation drawer overlap with fragments in android

Tags: android, fragment, navigation-drawer

I created navigation drawer in my main activity.When i click on navigation drawer item,i am launching fragment in my main activity.if click on navigation drawer icon again,drawer is overlappng with fragment.

i want to detach fragment when i open navigation drawer second time.

```
Context mContext;
UIController mController;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mPlanetTitles = { "Photos", "Videos", "Settings" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTitle = "test";

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    // Set the list's click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
    mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, /*
                                         * nav drawer icon to replace 'Up'
                                         * caret
                                         */
    R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
    R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
    ) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        }
    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
    // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle your other action bar items...

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }
}

public void selectItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content,
                        AlbumListFragment.newInstance()).commit();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [remove(android.app.Fragment)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#remove%28android.app.Fragment%29) or [popBackStackImmediate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#remove%28android.app.Fragment%29)

I assume you want something like:

```
...
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        //remove the fragment or pop it form the stack when you open the drawer?
        getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
}
...
```

Comment: From where i have to call this method?

Comment: inside your ActionBarDrawerToggle

Answer (score 0):

> Hi,The below code will help you

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

        // If the drawer is open, close it; vice versa
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: not solved with this solution.scenarios is like this  1. Open Navagation drawer and select one option ,After selecting option navigation drawer will close and content will display in screen. 2. If  I open navigation drawer again,in the background screen content is also showing along with Navigation drawer text.